# Inheritance from class and override method

Tags: python

I have two classes, one inherits of the other. When I hesitate and re-establish the function `get_commande_date` I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: BooksCommande.get_commandes_date() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

This is my code:

```
class BaseCommande(ABC):
    def __init__(self, list_of_commande: list) -> NoReturn:
        if list_of_commande:
            self.list_of_commande = list_of_commande
        self.commande_date = None
        self.comande_payed = None
        self.commande_price = None
        self.total_commandes = None
        self.process_commande(list_of_commande)
        super().__init__()

    def get_commandes_date(self, list_of_commande):
        return [commande['date_start'] for commande in list_of_commande]

    def process_commande(self, list_of_commande):
        self.commande_date = self.get_commandes_date(list_of_commande)

    def my_dict(self):
        return{
            "commende_date": self.commande_date}


class BooksCommande(BaseCommande):
    def __init__(self, list_of_commande: list) -> NoReturn:
        super().__init__(list_of_commande)
        self.commande_syplies = None
        self.commande_books = None
        self.process_books(list_of_commande)


    def get_commandes_date(self, list_of_commande, key):
        commande_date = []
        for commande in list_of_commande:
            cmd = {
                'date_start': commande['date_start'],
                'key': key,
                'date_end': commande['date_end'],
            }

            commande_date.append(cmd)
        return commande_date

    def get_commande_books(self, books: list):
        return 10

    def process_books(self, list_of_commande):
        self.books_list = self.get_commande_books(list_of_commande)

    def my_dict2(self):
        return{**super().my_dict(),
               "books": self.books_list
               }


commande_list = [{"date_start": "10/10/2021", "date_end": "12/15/2019"}]

print(BooksCommande(commande_list).my_dict2())
```

Is there a way to force `BaseCommande` to use the new redefined function or not? I really don't know how or from where to start.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but you are using `NoReturn` wrong. It doesn't indicate that a function returns `None`, but that it doesn't return *at all*: either it's an infinite loop, or that it *only* raises an exception. The return type of `__init__`, if specified, must be `None`.

Comment: yes noted thankyou

Comment: Changing the signature of `get_commands_date` like this is a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle. You are supposed to be able to use an instance of `BooksCommande` anywhere you can use an instance of `BaseCommande`, but you are introducing an unexpected parameter to the method.

Comment: can you give me an example please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're attempting to change the number of arguments that get passed to the `get_commandes_date()` method — something that cannot be done when defining a derived class.

The workaround is to make the argument optional. So in `class BaseCommande` declare a `key` parameter:

```
    def get_commandes_date(self, list_of_commande, key):
        return [commande['date_start'] for commande in list_of_commande]
```

And then give it a default value in the derived `BooksCommande` class version of the method. (I'm not sure what might make sense here, so just made it `None`.)

```
    def get_commandes_date(self, list_of_commande, key=None):
        commande_date = []
        for commande in list_of_commande:
            cmd = {
                'date_start': commande['date_start'],
                'key': key,
                'date_end': commande['date_end'],
            }

            commande_date.append(cmd)
        return commande_date
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, the issue with your code is that your subclass, `BooksCommande`, changes the signature of the `get_commandes_date` method to be different than the version in the base class, `BaseCommande`. While that might be a bad idea in an abstract sense, it's not forbidden by Python. The real trouble is that one of `BaseCommande`'s other methods, `process_commande`, tries to use the old signature, so everything breaks when that it gets called.

There is a fairly direct way to fix this, if you want to do so without dramatically changing the code. The general idea is for the two `BaseCommande` methods to call each other through a private reference. Even if one is overridden in a subclass, the private reference will remain pointing to the original implementation. Name mangling, with two leading underscores is often useful for this:

```
class BaseCommande(ABC):
    ...

    def get_commandes_date(self, list_of_commande):  # this method will be overridden
        return [commande['date_start'] for commande in list_of_commande]

    __get_commandes_date = get_commandes_date   # private reference to previous method

    def process_commande(self, list_of_commande):
        self.commande_date = self.__get_commandes_date(list_of_commande) # use it here
```

This kind of design won't always be correct, so you'll need to figure out if it's appropriate for your specific classes or not. If the fact that `process_commande` is calls `get_commandes_date` is supposed to be an implementation detail (and so it should keep behaving the same way, even though the latter method is overridden), then this is a good approach. If the relationship between the methods is part of the class's API, then you probably don't want to do this (since overriding the `get_commandes_date` method may be a deliberate way to change the results of `processess_commande` in a subclass).

Answer (score -1):

I think you want the method my_dict to have both my_dict and my_dict2 and have a boolean to trigger whenever you want to use one or the other.

```
def my_dict(self, trigger=False):
    if not Trigger:
       return{
           "commende_date": self.commande_date}
    else:
       return{**super().my_dict(),
           "books": self.books_list
```

Put this in place of your old my_dict method

```
def my_dict(self):
    return{
        "commende_date": self.commande_date}
```

Edit to add code